# Jquery Dialog window size

Tags: jquery-dialog

How do I make a JQuery dialog size to the size of the window?

I tried using 'auto' but that just makes it size to its elements, and I don't want to specifiy the px's exactly b/c that won't be dynamic. thanks!

Comment: are you using jquery library or the the jquery UI library, or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm taking a little bit of a guess here, but you can get the size of the window using:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
```

So, I would take that, and pass that value to the jQuery Dialog.

```
$( ".dialog" ).dialog({ height: windowHeight, width: windowWidth });
```